# Detect duplicated registries in Oracle

Tags: oracle, duplicates

I have a table in Oracle and I want to select all the duplicated values, I mean: I can detect that a register is duplicated because some column contains the same value:

```
ColumnA  ColumnB
1        A
2        A
3        A
4        B
```

I want to get something like:

```
1 A
1 A
1 A
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are the 1s in the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want all rows from the original table that have some duplicates in one column (ColumnB), you can use the following query:

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB FROM Table
WHERE ColumnB IN (
    SELECT ColumnB FROM Table
    GROUP BY ColumnB HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
)
```

For your original data, that would return:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
1       A
2       A
3       A
```

If it's enough to get all values that are used multiple times in the table, you can use a simpler query:

```
SELECT ColumnB FROM Table
GROUP BY ColumnB HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This would return just one row with `A`.